# Dark mode gets turned off on refeshing a page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create dark mode for my website and i use the following code, The problem is dark mode turns off on refreshing the page or opening a new page. I think there's a feature called `localstorage` in javascript. If anyone knows that, Please drop the method to fix this

```
<style>
body {background-color: white}
body.dark {background-color: black}
button {background-color: white; color: black}
body.dark button {background-color: black; color: white}
</style>
<script>
function toggleDark() {
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  if (body.classList.contains('dark')) {
    body.classList.remove('dark');
  } else {
    body.classList.add('dark');
  }
}

document.querySelector('#darkmode').addEventListener('click', toggleDark);
</script>
<button id="darkbutton" class="darkmode" onclick="toggleDark();myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Here is a pretty good guide on how to use [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). If you try that and it doesn't work, please edit your question by following the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. It makes it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: You can even use cookies here as well.

Comment: I'm just starting to code and I'm very new to javascript. Can anyone add `localStorage` to above code and drop me the answer. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: **MDN** has a nice documentation on [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), you just set and get the value you want using this API.  

If you want to store an object in json format, you can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) while setting and getting the value from localstorage.

Answer (score 3):

Put your data into cookie or local storage in javascript So When you Refresh the Page You Can Get that Value . You can Access local storage like .

```
localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark");
```

and you can get that data like

```
localStorage.getItem("mode");
```

now you will get your mode after refreshing a page Also.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the following code. Can you please run a snippet with it.

Comment: see Do one thing paste the code that i given and when i wrote a dark change that thing to your variable or whatever value that you want after refresh . now in localstorage.getitem() will give you that value or variable that you stored after refresh

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-using-localstorage-in-javascript-apps-ba44edb53a36/    see may be its helpful  for you . verify my answer if you like it

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working because you are not "saving" the user's choice in any way, so it will be reset to "light mode" every time the page loads.

To work around this, you can put your data into `localStorage` (a place where you can save data), or a cookie through JavaScript. That way, when you refresh the page, you can access the value and set it for the document.

`localStorage` is typically used since it is much easier to use with JavaScript compared to cookies.

The code below will set the key "theme" to "dark" using the `setItem` function, and get it using the `getItem` function.

```
localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
localStorage.getItem("theme");
```

For more information on `localStorage`, please [see this MDN article.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

I've updated your code snippet to work with this below:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body {background-color: white}
    body.dark {background-color: black}
    button {background-color: white; color: black}
    body.dark button {background-color: black; color: white}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="darkbutton" class="darkmode">Turn on dark mode</button>
<script>

const body = document.querySelector('body');
const button = document.querySelector('#darkbutton');
function toggleDark() {
  if (body.classList.contains('dark')) {
    body.classList.remove('dark');
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
    button.innerHTML = "Turn on dark mode";
  } else {
    body.classList.add('dark');
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
    button.innerHTML = "Turn off dark mode";
  }
}

if (localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark") {
  body.classList.add('dark');
  button.innerHTML = "Turn off dark mode";
}

document.querySelector('#darkbutton').addEventListener('click', toggleDark);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ilui85, I've tested the above code on codepen but that is not working. Here's the link <https://codepen.io/vkdatta27/pen/zYqQbmM>. Can you please check the errors i made [ if any ].  When i turn dark mode and turn on the page or move to other page, it is setting back to light mode, I want users to manually turn off when needed.

Comment: @ManiacPiano Whoops! I didn't realise that the `body` constant variable was defined inside the function, I've fixed it up now. Your code also had a few issues, such as the IDs and classes were mixed up, and you were using an event listener and the `onclick` attribute, meaning if the code had worked, it would have produced no effect anyway. ⁣In addition, in the onclick attribute, you were calling a second, undefined function `myFunction()`.
⁣
I've actually tested my answer this time!

Comment: @iliui85, its working but i have a last thing left. What if that button contains `Turn on dark mode`, `Turn off dark mode` rather than `Toggle dark mode`. I've struck with this issue, The button contains no value in the beginning and if i press it, value is appexed. See this; https://codepen.io/vkdatta27/pen/oNxrxad.

Comment: @ManiacPiano What issues are you having? I've tested your codepen, and can't find any issues with it (the button text changes with the theme, which I think is what you want). (Also, if this solution worked for you, could you mark the answer as accepted. Thanks!)

Comment: @ManiacPiano I've updated the code snippet above to change the button text. Is this the behaviour you expected, or have I misinterpreted you?